# Validation of at least one set of radio group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two groups of radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="a">
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="b">
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="c">


<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="e">
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="f">
<input type="radio" name="rb2" value="g">
```

Now, user:
1. has to select at least one value from either radio groups
2. can select one value from each of the two groups

I need to use javascript for validation. I can validate one or both groups, but how do I check for both?

Comment: does it have to be radio buttons? the downside is that once you select one radio button from the group, you can't pick "none" any longer. (standard radio button behavior).  From your description, none seems like a valid option for one group or the other.

Comment: exactly, we have two different groups. But I still need to check at least one is selected, it can be from group rb1 or rb2 or one radio from each group. makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do something like this...

```
$('#btnValidate').click(function() {
    var v1 = $('input:radio[name="rb1"]:checked').val();
    var v2 = $('input:radio[name="rb2"]:checked').val();

    if (!v1 && !v2 ) {
        alert('not valid');
    } else {
        alert('valid');
    }
});
```

working jsfiddle here...

http://jsfiddle.net/CEJLt/

Comment: perfect, thanks. Now I cannot have dialog boxes on page/alerts, is it possible to show this error, post form submission(marked red?)

Comment: sure.  I just used the alerts as an example.  Here's an updated jsfiddle that throws it in a div... http://jsfiddle.net/CEJLt/1/

Comment: There is one problem though, the validation error does not go away after I check the radio button, plus if I refresh the page, the readio button stays selected. Can we make it a conditional required?

Comment: if you want the error to go away when valid, just set the .html('valid') to .html('').

Comment: if you want the validation to fire on the change of the radio button, use this that event... $('input:radio').change(function(){ validation logic here. });

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this? attending_day_1:  {
            required: {
                depends: function() {
                    
                  return $('input:radio[name=attending_day_1]:checked').val() == 0;                }
            }
        },

Comment: This was working, until we found a bug, i have yoru type of validation: $('#submit').click(function() {
    var v1 = $('input:radio[name="attending_day_1"]:checked').val();
    var v2 = $('input:radio[name="attending_day_2"]:checked').val();
    
    if (!v1 && !v2 ) {
        $('.validation-error').html('*Please select attending day');
    } 
}); for radio buttons, but I am using validate functions for rest of the fields. If all those fields are filled in, your radio button validation does not stop page from submitting. help?